# How to send keyboard scan codes manually?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm working on a project that needs to emulate a keypress of the Windows key.  I've tried SendKeys.Send to no avail.

Specifically, the windows key needs to come in concert with a button. That is, I want to send Windows Key and plus / minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be overkill, but you could try using [AutoItX](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) which is a way to use AutoIt as a DLL. I've only written standalone scripts, but I know AutoIt makes it very easy to simulate pressing the Windows key.

For example, to open the run dialog is just:

> Send("#r") ;Win + R = run

Answer (score 7):

I would add that it is **often unlikely for you to find lower level functions like these in the .NET framework**. If you were confused as to why the suggestions both pointed to "non C#" functions, then you probably could use some details on [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

Basically there are ways to define C# functions that "tie" them to Windows API functions that do not exist within .NET assemblies (Instead they are typically implemented in C++ and available as a standard DLL). This process is considered to be "(Windows) Platform Invoking" (thus P/Invoke).

It can be a bit wobbly at first to match up all the data types between C++ and C# style calls, but fortunately, there are others out there that have paved the way.

The suggested function, [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx), has a [PInvoke wrapper](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput) over at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net). This wrapper class, when available in your assembly, will allow you to call SendInput as if it were a C# function.

PInvoke.net is basically a PInvoke wiki for well known API calls in windows, and typically has a C#/VB.NET wrapper of API calls.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is using [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx) keydown (called ExtendedKey) with the LWin value of the [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enum, then keydown second character (+), and keyup both keys.

I do not believe SendKeys works with the Windows key as a modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) or the older [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(VS.85).aspx)